# How to make 2 txt into 1 batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm working on a script that will take 2 (or more) txt and make it to 1
Here's my code:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\
echo this is 1.txt > 1.txt
echo this is 2.txt > 2.txt
copy "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1.txt" >> source.txt
copy "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\2.txt" >> source.txt
```

i have tried whit:

```
echo "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1.txt" >> source.txt
echo "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\2.txt" >> source.txt
```

but it just ends up whit:

The file cannot be copied onto itself.
        0 file(s) copied.
The file cannot be copied onto itself.
        0 file(s) copied.

or

"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1.txt" 
"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\2.txt"

i hope you can help me whit my little problem :)
Regards Jellex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to append two files together, you can just use:

```
copy "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1.txt" + "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\2.txt" sorce.txt
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
type "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1.txt" >> sorce.txt
type "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\2.txt" >> sorce.txt
```

Here's why your approaches weren't working:

1. `copy a.txt >> b.txt` is the same as appending the output of `copy a.txt` to `sorce.txt`. Since `copy a.txt` doesn't specify a destination file, you get an error.
2. `echo "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1.txt" >> sorce.txt` is the same as appending the output of `echo "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1.txt"` to `sorce.txt`. All `echo "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1.txt"` does is print `"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
type 1.txt 2.txt > sorce.txt
```

Then to verify content:

```
type sorce.txt
```

copy is used to copy files rather than cataloguing their content.